# Python: Fix up to 4 float number result in Complex Math

Tags: python, math, floating-point, precision

I am solving a quadratic equation in Python, but result is giving me 16 decimals

```
import cmath

a = 1
b = -4
c = 1
5
#Calculate the discriminant
d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)
#Find the two solutions:
sol1 = (-b-cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
sol2 = (-b+cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
print("The solutions are {0} and {1} ".format(sol1,sol2))
```

The solutions are (0.2679491924311228+0j) and (3.732050807568877+0j)

I am trying this:

```
print("The solutions are %0.4{0} and %0.4{1} ".format%(sol1,sol2)
```

#But is not working`

Comment: You put the formatting inside the `{}`: `{0:.4f}`

Comment: Thank you Barmar, that was the solution, plus that is not needed to place the % symbol nor the 0 prior to 4 number

Comment: @OtonielRamirez, _print(f"The solutions are {sol1:.4f} and {sol2:.4f} ")_.  _[string — Common string operations — Python 3.11.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)_.